# Perguntar antes de excluir dados do banco

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli, delete

Tenho esse codigo:

```
<?php             
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuario ORDER BY id"))
{
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing=0 style=border-collapse: collapse bordercolor='#41c88c'>";

        // definir cabeçalhos de tabela
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Nome</th> <th>Email</th></tr>";

        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            // cria uma linha para cada registro
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->nome . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->email . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='edit_usu.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Editar</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Deletar</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
    }
}
?>
```

e preciso que uma caixa de texto pergunte antes se realmente quero excluir os dados, qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso?
grato.

tentei usar dessa forma:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function delete(){
        var agree=confirm("deseja deletar os dados??");
        if (agree)
            return true ;
        else
            return false ;
    }
</script>
```

mas não sei como usar a variavél *$confirm*

Comment: Ah, o nome da sua função é `delete`. `delete` é uma palavra reservada do JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete. Muda o nome da função (para `remove`, por exemplo) e tudo deve funcionar.

Comment: delete foi apenas como exemplo, a variável que utilizei foi idlink e o que eu não consigo compreender é o erro de sintaxe que acorre nesta linha     **echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "' onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja deletar esse registro?');">Deletar</a></td>";**

Comment: Eu editei minha resposta. Como o @People mencionou, faltou escapar as aspas duplas por causa do `echo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A forma mais simples de se fazer isso é usando JavaScript, através da função [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) e do evento [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick):

```
<a href="http://google.com.br" onclick="return confirm('Deseja mesmo acessar o Google?');">Ir para o Google!</a>
```

Você pode ver isso funcionando nesse exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/tbcww98q/

Abaixo você pode ver como ficaria o seu código:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->nome . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->email . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='edit_usu.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Editar</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "' onclick=\"return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja deletar esse registro?');\">Deletar</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: eu estava na dúvida de como usar confirm, obrigado por esclarecer minhas dúvidas, porem acusa erro de sintaxe, não sei como empregar a função junto com _row->id_

Comment: Por que você precisaria utilizar `$row->id` no `confirm`?

Comment: Tem como você editar sua pergunta e postar seu novo código?

Comment: é uma tabela com vários dados, '$row' busca o id para poder deletar.

Comment: Mas no seu código tu não tá usando confirm. Tem como postar a maneira que você tentou utilizar e erro que ocorreu?

Comment: Você esqueceu de escapar as aspas duplas dentro da string, a linha com o **onclick** deve ficar assim: `echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "' onclick=\"return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja deletar esse registro?');\">Deletar</a></td>";`

Comment: Obrigado, já arrumei :)

Comment: com ajuda de vocês deu certo, agradeço muito!

Answer (score 1):

Teste este código assim, ele faz exatamente o que você quer ... se escolher **cancelar** ele simplesmente para o script e não dá `refresh` na página, se der um `Ok`, ele parte para delete.php com captação do `id` por `GET` e faz o que quiser conforme as instruções no script em andamento, no caso `delete.php`.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dados ORDER BY id"))
{

        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {

            echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing=0 style=border-collapse: collapse bordercolor='#41c88c'>";


                // definir cabeçalhos de tabela
               echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Nome</th> <th>Email</th></tr>";

                while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                {
                // cria uma linha para cada registro
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->nome . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row->email . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='edit_usu.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Editar</a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "' onclick=\"return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja deletar esse registro?'); return false;\">Deletar</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }

            echo "</table>";

         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendo pq ainda insistem em passar o id via GET através de um link.
Será que não perceberam que o link vai aparecer completo para o usuário com o id no final, daí se ele quiser fazer o "mau" com seu DB, pode ficar trocando o id e dando enter deletando os mesmo só para zoar com vc.
Faça um submit via POST atrelando um pop up ou até mesmo uma nova página onde lá vc configura um confirmar com outro submit que irá levar até ao arquivo que delata por require, dessa forma este arquivo não vai ficar exposto e nem o id, impossibilitando que qualquer um que tenha o link de delete simplesmente lhe cause grandes dores de cabeça.