# Confirmar antes de fazer a alteração

Tags: ajax

Quando altero o evento no calendário, antes de alterar pedir para confirmar:
o código:

```
function edit(event){
            start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            if(event.end){
                end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            }else{
                end = start;
            }

            id =  event.id;

            Event = [];
            Event[0] = id;
            Event[1] = start;
            Event[2] = end;

            $.ajax({
             url: './updatehoradataeventoLar',
             type: "POST",
             data: {Event:Event},
             success: function(rep) {
                    if(rep == 'OK'){
                        alert('Atividade Guardada correctamente');
                    }else{
                        alert('Tente novamente!'); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Desta forma só alerta que a actividade foi guardada correctamente, mas antes de aparecer esse alerta pretendo que apareça a pedir se pretende mesmo alterar o evento, caso seja sim altera se for não mantém.

As respostas dessa pergunta não me ajudaram a resolver a minha questão, porque no meu caso, quando faço a alteração é por arrasto do evento já marcado e não tenho nenhum botão ou link para adicionar o `onclick` e pretendia fazer o mesmo dentro do `sucess` do `ajax`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Perguntar antes de excluir dados do banco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33621/perguntar-antes-de-excluir-dados-do-banco)

Comment: Antes de executar toda a função `edit` você deseja realizar uma confirmação?

Comment: @Pedro Paulo, sim, antes de fazer alteração pedir a confirmação se quer realizar mesmo essa alteração

Comment: Então pesquise pela função `confirm`. Ela é a solução, não um "botão com onclick".

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesta resposta que tem um `confirm`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74705/8063

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função `confirm(mensagem)` para saber se o usuário confirmou a ação de edição:

```
function edit(event){
    if(confirm('Confirma a alteração dos dados?')) {
        start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        if(event.end){
            end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        }else{
            end = start;
        }

        id =  event.id;

        Event = [];
        Event[0] = id;
        Event[1] = start;
        Event[2] = end;

        $.ajax({
         url: './updatehoradataeventoLar',
         type: "POST",
         data: {Event:Event},
         success: function(rep) {
                if(rep == 'OK'){
                    alert('Atividade Guardada correctamente');
                }else{
                    alert('Tente novamente!'); 
                }
            }
        });
  }
}
```